# Proj4Leaflet - Defining World Eckert IV

Tags: leaflet, proj4js

I'm trying to make a Leaflet map with World Eckert IV projection using Proj4Lefalet.  From what I understand, I should be able to define my CRS like so:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('ESRI:54012',
    '+proj=eck4 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ',
    {
        resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128],
        origin: [0, 0]
    });
```

Given that [ESRI:54012 is the code for this projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54012/).  However, I 
get the error:

`uncaught exception: ESRI:54012`

I cannot find an EPSG code for this projection, just an ESRI code.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: What versions of Leaflet, proj4, and proj4leaflet are you using?

Comment: haver you ever fixed that?

Comment: @ius: The problem actually turned out to be that I was using a basemap, for which projections are rather unpredictable.  When I removed the basemap and used only vector features, it was fine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. How can I remove the basemap and use only vector features?